# What is the difference between LinearRegression and SGDRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I understand that both `LinearRegression` class and `SGDRegressor` class from `scikit-learn` performs linear regression. However, only `SGDRegressor` uses Gradient Descent as the optimization algorithm.

Then what is the optimization algorithm used by `LinearRegression`, and what are the other significant differences between these two classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**LinearRegression** always uses the least-squares as a loss function.

For **SGDRegressor** you can specify a loss function and it uses Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) to fit. For SGD you run the training set one data point at a time and update the parameters according to the error gradient.

In simple words - you can train SGDRegressor on the training dataset, that does not fit into RAM. Also, you can update the SGDRegressor model with a new batch of data without retraining on the whole dataset.

Comment: Why there is a change in `SGDRegressor` output i.e., coefficients and intercept when using `squared_error` as loss function? Is it possible to get the same coefficients from SGDRegressor as well? Which loss function will help in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the algorithm used by **LinearRegression**, we must have in mind that there is (in favorable cases) an analytical solution (with a formula) to find the coefficients which minimize the least squares:

theta = (X'X)^(-1)X'Y  (1)

where X' is the the transpose matrix of X.

In the case of non-invertibility, the inverse can be replaced by the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse calculated using "singular value decomposition" (**SVD**). And even in the case of invertibility, the SVD method is faster and more stable than applying the formula (1).

**PS -** No LaTeX (MathJaX) in Stackoverflow ???

--
Pierre (from France)