# How to create a model on time series data and update it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a large dataset of 23k rows. That data looks like something below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Date': ["1-1-2020", '1-1-2020', "1-2-2020", "1-2-2020"], 'Stock': ["FB", "F", "FB", "F"], 
     "last_price": [230,8,241,9], "price":[241,9,240,8.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Date      Stock_id   last_price  price
0   1-1-2020  5           230        241.0
1   1-1-2020  41          8          9.0
2   1-2-2020  5           241        240.0
3   1-2-2020  41          9          8.5
```

Note that data includes many stocks on many different dates. How can I create a model that uses the feature for example last_price and stock id to predict next-day price? And that uses the old data to re-train the data.

Now, this was the best thing I could do. I used LinearRegression but any other model advice can work.

```
X = df[['Stock_id', 'last_price']]
y = df[['price']]

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model  

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = lm.predict(X_test)
result = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})

Index   Actual  Predicted
487     45      32
4154    420     512
```

Is there a way where the model is trained on the first 3000 rows? Then the model makes a prediction for say date 12-11-2020 and then adds 12-11-2020 info to make the prediction for 12-12-2020 and so on?

I was hoping to get something like this.

```
Date       Actual   Predicted
12-11-2020  45      32
12-11-2020  420     512
12-12-2020  43      34
12-12-2020  423     513
```

Comment: Please refrain from apologizing, thanking etc in SO posts (edited out); stick only to the point. Plus, question has nothing to do with `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited out).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think having the id in your training dataset is appropriate since ids and comparing them does not give any useable information and may result in a bad calculated linear function for your model. ID just signifies that you are talking about a specific stock and is constant for a specific stock in the whole dataset. Also the value of the Stock_id cannot does not have any meaning that can be used for comparing stocks together, for example having a Stock_id = 1 and Stock_id = 2 doesn't mean these 2 are closer together than Stock_id = 1 and Stock_id = 100, they are just names. So I think you should split your original dataset based on the Stock_id and only include last_price in each of these new training datasets (X). You can do that in several ways, one them being the groupby function of pandas:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.Stock_id)
stock_1= grouped.get_group(1)
```

After that, you can use a for loop on the unique value of your Stock_id column to get all the ids and their dataframes. Then you define a regression model for each of these new datasets and use the fit method to train it.

To retrain or update your regression model, LinearRegression does not support partial fit and I think you need to use the fit method again each time you want to update your model. You can use the first N rows of each user to fit the model, then predict the value for the next last_price and add the predicted value to the N rows and re-fit the model on the extended dataset. However, if your model actually calculates a good line to predict the data, I don't think you will see that much of a difference by adding new predictions to the training dataset.

Another option is to use SGDRegressor instead of LinearRegression, since it has a `partial_fit()` method allows for incremental training which lets you train your model on new data without re-training the model on the whole dataset. You can find the documentation for this model [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html). Also this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643225/what-is-the-difference-between-linearregression-and-sgdregressor) explains the difference between SGDRegressor and Linear Regression.

If you still want to use LinearRegression and retrain the model, I suggest you use batches of data for updating your model, instead of retraining it on each new predicted value. You can wait for your predicted values to get to a certain number, for example 10, and then add these 10 new values to your training dataset and retrain the model just once. This answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12765) explains 3 approaches in retraining the model which might be useful for you.